# Is there a way to know the online status of a user in Azure communication services Chat?

Tags: azure-communication-services

I have been trying to build a chat application using ACS javascript SDK, I couldn't find any details on how to show the online/offline status of a participant in a chat-thread.
Is there a way to do that in ACS? or do we have to build a custom solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, user presence is not supported in ACS yet (and there is no integration with Microsoft Teams presence). For now, you have to build your own custom solution.

If you're interested in a feature that's not supported in ACS, it's always a good idea to share your thoughts at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/934536-azure-communication-services.